# MVC jQuery autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to set up autocomplete for a text box on a page, but I cannot get it to work.

I have my bundles configured:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js", // version is 2.2.1
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js" // version is 1.11.4
));
```

In the controller, the function that returns the list of users.

```
public JsonResult GetInternalUsers() {
    var results = db.Users
        .Select(x => new {
            UserId = x.UserId,
            UserName = x.UserName,
        }
    ).ToList();

    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The editor boxes are dynamically added, so below, XXX is replaced with an integer (i.e., `Attendees0`).

```
<input id="AttendeesXXX" type="text" name="Attendees[X]" class="form-control col-md-6" />
```

And finally, the actual script:

```
$('#Attendees' + internalAttendees).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetInternalUsers", "Events")',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.UserName, value: item.UserId }
                }))
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#Attendees' + internalAttendees).val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

The part that's throwing me the most is that when I type `$('#Attendees' + internalAttendees)`, the intellisense never brings up `autocomplete`, so I don't even know if I'm including the correct libraries.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Dan Champagne , try turning on developer tools f12 and clicking on the 'network' tab and then reload that page. Are you seeing jquery loading before jquery UI? If you can confirm that jQuery IS loading first what does your console say?

Comment: @mwwallace8 Yes, jquery is loading before the ui library.

Comment: And the console says what? I assume there is some error in browser console if the script isn't working/recognizing autocomplete.

Comment: @mwwallace8 `Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.` Nothing that relates to jquery.

Comment: Ahh. Well it sounds like the easy stuff isn't the case! Can you get a real simple autocomplete working? Like the one from the jquery UI website under default functionality? If that works then its probably something to do with your selector/variables, etc. If it doesn't work then its probably something to do with the versions or order of the scripts (which we ruled out). Good luck!

Comment: @mwwallace8 this is actually the first time I'm trying this. Can you point me at a simple way of doing it? I might be able to work it out from there.

Comment: Sure. Go here and click on view source. If you can load your scripts like you currently are.. and get their code to work.. you're in decent shape. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @DanChampagne When does that script run? Before or after the input element is added to the page?

Comment: @thiag0 It runs just after the element is added to the page.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that should be checked.

Something that I do is declare my selector as a variable

```
var $myElement = $('#myElement');
```

so that I can set a breakpoint and inspect $myElement to see if it has a value.

Next, set a breakpoint and make sure you're actually hitting your code since the elements being dynamically added.  If the code in the document ready happens before the element is created, the event won't be attached to the element.  You may have to add the element and then run code that attaches.

The actual call looks correct, if you set a breakpoint in your controller does it get hit?

But I'm confused.  Why is this an autocomplete?  Don't you want to pass down a value in the "data" parameter of the ajax call?  As it stands now you aren't filtering your response at all.

Answer (score -2):

For MVC architecture you must delete the already embedded

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Jquery") 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Jqueryval")
```

from all .cshtml files at the end and for also `views/Shared/_layout.cshtml` at the  end and put our jQuery suitable files on his suitables .cshtmls files in head...and let's enjoy. put on head..these files

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

//////////////////////code behind download  button//////////////////////

Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=help.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/doc/help.pdf"));
Response.End();
```